How can toggle between three input methods?
There are three input methods in my ibus framework:

I have set the ctrl + space  as toggling key between the three input methods.

I want to toggle between the three input methods when click ctrl+space:
English-English(US)
Chinese-Intelligent PinYin
Chinese-Rime

When the initial input method is English-English(US)，
click ctrl+space ，toggle to Chinese-Intelligent PinYin
click ctrl+space ，toggle to English-English(US)
click ctrl+space ，toggle to Chinese-Intelligent PinYin
The Chinese-Rime never called out ,How can toggle between three input methods?
